# php looping interpolation is it possible?

Tags: php, interpolation

I have the code bellow:

```
$r.="<$starttag";foreach($ATTR as $attr) $r.=" {$attr}"; $r.=">$a<$endtag> ";
```

I would like to write as something like:

```
$r.="<$starttag {@$ATTR, } >$a<$endtag>";
```

or in any other way that avoids exiting the string being interpolated
is there any similar possibility in PHP or a trick to do it ?

Comment: have a look at `sprintf`. You can use a `%s` and the value you put in it would be `implode(' ', $ATTR)`

Comment: Please format your code in a more standard manner. I had to read it four times before I could figure out what it does. If you really want to adhere to a standard see: [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). I can understand that you don't care about these things, but when you're communicating with other programmers this can become important.

Comment: @CornelRaiu You could use `implode()` without `sprintf()`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware agree, but `sprintf` would make the code more readable in my opinion

Comment: I tried 'echo "<$starttag {explode(' ',$ATTR} $endtag>";' but it does not seem to give the requested output.

Comment: you need to implode, not explode.

Comment: It would need to be: `echo "<$starttag " . implode(" ", $ATTR) . ">";`. Sorry, took me a bit of editing to get that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using `sprintf` because, in my opinion, it makes the code easier to read:

```
// data for testing
$ATTR = [
    'attr1="attr1value"', 
    'attr2="attr2value"', 
    'attr3="attr3value"'
];

$starttag = "a";
$endtag = "a";
$a = "Value";

$r = "";
// end data for testing

$r .= sprintf(
  "<%s %s>%s</%s>",
  $starttag,
  implode(" ", $ATTR),
  $a,
  $endtag
);
```

If you don't want to go down that path, you can do a simple concat with the imploded values of the $ATTR array like so:

`$r .= "<$starttag " . implode(" ", $ATTR) . ">$a<$endtag>";`

Comment: Also might be a use for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php